# Do I have to use wp_create_nonce for security purpose in wordpress ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am creating a plugin. I know if I call the ajax through wordpress `admin-ajax.php`, I should use `wp_create_nonce` for security purpose.

But how about I only call the function through a php file url in ajax? That's faster. I want to know, should I do ajax calls through `admin-ajax.php` for security purpose, or is it OK to call a normal php file url?

Comment: Do things the WordPress way :) - use admin-ajax.php.

Comment: I only want to know if I use ajax but not use admin-ajax.php, will that be easier for injection.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably true that calling a function with a standard php file url in ajax is faster but the problem is you see, functions in your php file can be called via ajax from anywhere.

But on the other hand WordPress has a built in system for verifying whether or not the ajax request comes from your website or some other website. Whenever you use `wp_create_nonce`, WordPress creates a verification number and sends it out to any page in **only your website** and that's because the page requested is in your website. WordPress then uses that number to cross check with the initial number that was created `(also known as the nonce)`.

So it is very safe to use `wp_create_nonce` and it is also best practice.

Comment: security always is the top consideration. Although the speed is almost 50x faster than the admin-ajax.php. So, do you have any way to boost the speed if I use admin-ajax.php to load ajax.

Comment: I can't tell unless i see your codes for ajax and WordPress actions